# Install php7 (7.0.4 or 7.0.6RC) on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, php, repository

Is there any available repository which would allow me to install PHP 7.0.4 or 7.0.6 (testing version) on my Ubuntu 14.04 server?

I only found a way to use `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, but it only installs me 7.0.5 NTS, whereas:

- I need TS (i'm using apache2handler)
- 7.0.5 doesn't work for me (zend-code, which is a dependency for my project, doesn't work with this version).

Any ideas?

Comment: Manual compiling is the only option left to you - because 7.0.4 had some security holes I think that landed fixes in 7.0.5

Comment: @ThomasW. maybe there are any testing repos with 7.0.6 in there? For example RHEL's remi-testing repo has php 7.0.6RC.

Comment: Ondrej's usually quick to get new releases in his PPA.

Comment: @muru Yeah, but I don't know when 7.0.6 is going to be released, whereas I quite need to update server on this week. I found some repository with 7.0.4 on the launchpad.net, but I am not sure if I can somehow add that repository in order to get packages from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found an answer by myself.

`Ondrej's` has an [experimental repository](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-qa) which contains PHP 7.0.6RC version.

Comment: I also have a `ppa:ondrej/php-zts`, but the builds are broken and I haven't had time to fix it yet. So if you have a spare time and you know how to build Debian packages, I could use some help.

Comment: JFTR the ppa:ondrej/php-qa repository now has a working version of PHP 7.0 ZTS.